# Prestashop hide Pre-tax wholesale price for employee

Tags: prestashop

Hi I run the latest version of PrestaShop v1.6.1.1 
I want to hide the wholesale price for employees but not for the SuperAdmin.
Found the template prices.tpl but dont know how to do the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside price.tpl you have access to `$employee` object, so find the HTML code that contains wholesale price (there is `<div class="form-group"> ... </div>`) and wrap it in next condition:

```
{if $employee->id_profile == 1}
<div class="form-group"> 
...html code...
</div>
{/if}
```

where `1` it is Id for SuperAdmin profile by default.

Comment: Thanks this was easy.

Comment: where is the location of price.tpl? what version of your prestashop. the file doesn't exist in prestashop.

Comment: @MaXi32 the question about ver 1.6.x and about backoffice, so price(s).tpl file is in admin theme products controllers directory.